# Angular5: IE caching js bundles

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular-cli

I have my angular5 application which is built using angular-cli. When I build the app and deploy it everything works fine. But when I deploy a new version and the load the page, IE is still showing the old content. Is there a way to not cache the files.
I have ng build -prod --output-hashing all in my command.

I added this in my index.html but it didn't help.

```
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
```

Comment: try to set expires content "-1". https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/234067/how-to-prevent-caching-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `--outputHashing= true` in ng build this will give random names to changed files

read more at https://angular.io/cli/build

Edit to force reload HTML file
use

```
<meta http-equiv=“Expires” content=”-1″>
```

Source: https://www.lifewire.com/force-page-load-from-server-3466696

Comment: I have this already. But as it is caching the index.html file, which has reference to the old bundles, old bundles are used.

Comment: I meant IE is caching the old index.html file.

Comment: When a new version of the app is deployed on the server, client will not clear the browser cache. When he re opens the app, new version of the app should be displayed. If old version of index.html sits in his/her browser, if he re-opens the app, old version of the app will be loaded instead of the new version.

Comment: can you try <meta http-equiv=“Expires” content=”-1″>

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

> ng build --prod

It appends a random string to bundle names.

Comment: I have this already. But as it is caching the index.html file, which has reference to the old bundles, old bundles are used.